# Creating and storing XML docs in Netbeans 7

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, netbeans-7, netbeans7.0

Because I need a free and reliable XML editor, I just installed the Netbeans 7.0 + JDK bundle from Oracle.com. I will not be using Java nor will I be learning it at this point. I am learning XML and need to work with it for a project. I will send the XML docs to someone else who will include it in their program.
Product Version: NetBeans IDE 7.0
Java: 1.6.0_26; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 20.1-b02
Not knowing Java, I finally found a way to get an XML editor up on IDE, but am not sure if I selected the correct type of Java project to access the XML editor, and am not sure where to specify to store the docs, etc. That is, when it says to select a new project (so that I can open an XML editor), I selected Java Application. But I do not know the significance of this. Does it matter if I select Java Desktop Application, Java Class Library, Java Project with Existing Sources, or Java free-form project for the new project if I will be creating several XML docs for one project? Also, it later asks me if I want to store the XML doc that I just opened and created in the src or elsewhere. Does this matter where I store the XML docs that I will create? I could not find much information on the net about using the XML editor with Netbeans except for one older tutorial that assumed one knew Java. Thanks very much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans is overkill for xml files. Use something lightweight like Notepad++, Geany or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm using Netbeans to be in sync with other project members who are long-distance.  I understand that Netbeans is overkill but need to use it. I have Notepad++ but I don't seem to get the same kind of automatic XML support that Netbeans provides. Have you used Notepad++ for big XML projects? I know you can select XML as a language in Notepad++ but it can get tedious. Do you agree?